# Connecting 2 Sales Cloud Salesforce Organizations

Tags: integration, appexchange

We are looking to run two sales cloud orgs, the intention being that we want two groups of users working from similar data sets, but we cannot have them in the same instance even with sharing settings set up. We don't want the data to get stale, so we are looking for a way to connect these orgs and update specific objects. For instance, if, in Instance A, an address for a contact is updated, we want instance B to reflect that as soon as possible.

Curious if anyone has done this or has another solution that has worked for them?

Answer (score 2):

Integration is a broad topic, and this site works best with single, narrowly-scoped issues. That said...

If your orgs are relatively similar to one another in terms of customizations, then [Salesforce to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.business_network_intro.htm&type=5) is worth looking into (no added cost, a standard Salesforce feature).

Beyond that, I think things start to become some mix of expensive and cusomization-heavy. The next easiest thing I can think of (other than digging through the app exchange and spending money for licences) is to use the REST api to update records in the target org, which would involve:

- On the sending side

  - a trigger (to capture the changed data)
  - an @future annotated method (to allow you to make a callout)
  - a Remote Site Setting (so Salesforce doesn't prevent your callout)
- On the receiving side

  - A Connected App
  - with a certificate (access to the private key for the sending side) to allow you to authenticate with the receiving side using the JWT OAuth 2.0 flow